# Is there any difference of CPU Scheduling between debian os and linux os?

Tags: linux, debian, cpu, scheduling

I think it's no difference but I am still confused with some docs on Internet so I came here to ask the professional my question. Please help me, I need this because I gonna write it to my reports

Thanks for reading

Comment: Linux is a kernel. Debian is an OS running the Linux kernel.

Comment: Debian is an OS/distribution using the Linux kernel. So it doesn't really make sense to ask for a difference between the two. It is a categorical error.